# How to to avoid "Port 22: Connection refused" error on SSH port (22)?

Tags: ssh, debian, openvpn, connection, connection-refused

I have a server where I just use openssh, openvpn and rabbitmq (which requires a lot of erlang dependencies).

Every time I reboot my server I can't access to it anymore getting

> Port 22: Connection Refused

And I have to install everything from scratch.

What should I check to avoid this problem??

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Answer (score 4):

To view your firewall settings in a terminal perform the following: -

```
sudo iptables -L -n
```

you looking for somehting ike this

```
# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

if no port ssh (22) rule is set then try:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

save current iptables firewall rules to a file called `/root/dsl.fw`, type:

```
# iptables-save > /root/dsl.fw
```

To restore iptables rules, enter:

```
iptables-restore < /root/dsl.fw
```

To restore rules automatically upon Linux system reboot add following command to your `/etc/rc.local` file, enter:

```
# vi /etc/rc.local
```

Append the line:

```
/sbin/iptables-restore < /root/dsl.fw
```

---

To check what init services are running and at what run level try this in a terminal

```
ls /etc/rc*.d
```

if sshd is not listed do then enter this in your terminal:

```
update-rc.d ssh enable
```

Comment: the last line is not working.. =/

Comment: Type in terminal and post the results of  `dpkg --get-selections | grep ssh`

Answer (score 3):

> Port 22: Connection Refused

This message indicates that a firewall is actively blocking your connection attempt or alternatively that sshd is not listening on that port.

Verify that:

1. The iptables rules applied on boot **allow** traffic on port 22
2. sshd is set to start on boot

Comment: It may also mean the service is not running.

Answer (score -2):

Just try (as root)

`sudo apt-get install ssh`

i havn't ssh server in standard ubuntu desktop installation

Comment: While this might actually get one past the problem by reinstalling and restarting ssh, it's hardly a solution.  One would be better served trying to find out *why* this is happening and prevent it from happening again.